# crystal reports - active employee formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to make a report that gives an 'active snapshot' for a past month. For example - how many active women are employed in October?

The date (a particular month) I am going for the active snapshot will change. I am using the following fields in my formula employee.hire_date is the date the employee started with our organization, employee.term_date is the date employment ended.

I am then grouping employees by gender and using the employee.gender and then the employee.name

What do you guys think about this logic?
The employee.hire_date can be anytime during that month, minus the last day? The employee.term_date can be anytime during that month, minus the last day? I am saying minus the last day because the employee had to have worked at least 1 day during the month. I am stumped....

Then make a formula, and set the parameters to the first and last of the month?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the right direction and it might help if i tell that i think you need to approach 6 different situations for a given month. The point is if there is an intersection between the employee working period and the given month.

Suppose:

- h is the hire_date
- T is the term_date
- m is the fist day of a given month
- M is the last day of a given month

See these "timelines": (sorry, a little bit confusing)

```
h..T..m........M...... (1- start and end before the month, no intersection) 
......m..h..T..M...... (2- start and end inside the month, there is intersection) 
......m........M..h..T (3- start and end after the month, no intersection) 
h.....m........M.....T (4- start before the month, end after the month, intersection)
h.....m....T...M...... (5- start before the month, end inside the month, intersection) 
......m...h....M.....T (6- start inside the month, end after the month, intersection)
```

So, there is intersection if h <= M and T >= m (hurray, karnaugh map!).

To ignore the last day, as you said, maybe it would be: h < M and T > m.

Create a running total field that count the employees by gender if there is intersection.

EDIT: Maybe the full formula should be:

```
{EMPLOYEE.Hire_Date}<={?Last of Month} and (
  isnull({EMPLOYEE.Termination_Date}) OR 
  {EMPLOYEE.Termination_Date}>={?First of Month}
)
```

Comment: So i tried this formula in the running totals:

if not(isnull({EMPLOYEE.Termination_Date}))
then {EMPLOYEE.Hire_Date}<={?Last of Month}
and {EMPLOYEE.Termination_Date}>={?First of Month}

and then to reset on the change of every employee.gender grouping. But i am only getting a count of 8.... and i know there are about 150 active employees. Is there something else I am missing? @heringer

Comment: I think you need to deal with null termination date. I suppose if there is no termination date, then the employee is active. So, you need an OR clause. See edited answer. Does it make sense?